# show posted data after submission with all old submission

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form, which have some input fields and also have some check box fields. If any one fill fields and select some checkbox and then submit. Then some data according submission shows on another div.

Now If same person again fill that fields after first submission and select checkbox and submit. Then some data according submission shows on div. But it replace old submission content. I need all submission content, on div including all old submission content.

My code is:

```
<form  class="reservation-form mb-0" action="" method="post" novalidate autocomplete="off">

    <input name="name1" class="form-control required " type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" aria-required="true" required>
    <input name="age" class="form-control required " type="number" placeholder="Enter Age" aria-required="true" required>
    <select required id="selectarea" class="form-control" name="selectgender"> 
        <option>Select Gender</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select> 

    <?php
        $query1=mysql_query("select * from lab_location_package_rel where city_id='$selectcity1' AND area_id='$selectarea1' AND lab_id='$selectlab1'") or die (mysql_error());          
        while($value = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
            $mrp=$value['mrp'];
            $opp=$value['offer_price_perc'];
            $package_id=$value['package_id'];
            $per=$mrp*$opp/100;
            $total=$mrp-$per;
            $query2=mysql_query("select * from package_master where id='$package_id'") or die (mysql_error());
            $value2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
            ?>     
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="namec[]" value="<?php echo $value["id"]; ?>" />
                    <label for="checkbox">
                        <b>Package Name:</b> <?php $package_title1=$value2['package_title']; echo $package_title1;?> <br>
                        <b>MRP:</b>  <strike><?php $mrp1=$value['mrp']; echo $mrp1; ?>  </strike><br>
                        <b>Offer Price:</b>  <?php $total1=$total; echo $total1; ?>       
                    </label>
                </div>

            </li>
        <?php } 
    ?>
    <input type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-warning" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Now After submission, for display code:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <h5>Patient Details</h5>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Sex</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <?php if(isset($_POST["submit"])==true)
                { ?>
                    <td><?php echo $_POST['name1']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $_POST['age']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $_POST['selectgender']; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Update</a></td>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br /><br />

    <h5>Package Details</h5>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Package</th>
                <th>MRP</th>
                <th>Offer Price</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <?php
                extract($_POST);
                foreach($_POST['namec'] as $selected){
                    $query1=mysql_query("select * from lab_location_package_rel where id='$selected'") or die (mysql_error());          
                     while($value = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
                         $mrp=$value['mrp'];
                         $opp=$value['offer_price_perc'];
                         $package_id=$value['package_id'];
                         $per=$mrp*$opp/100;
                         $total=$mrp-$per;
                         $query2=mysql_query("select * from package_master where id='$package_id'") or die (mysql_error());
                         $value2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
                         ?>
                         <tr>
                             <td><?php echo $value2['package_title'];  ?></td>
                             <td><strike><?php echo $value['mrp']; ?></strike></td>
                             <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
                             <td>Delete</td>
                         </tr>                 
                         <?php
                     }
                }
            }
            ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: P.S. edited your tags because there's no JS or ajax anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thank you for reply..But please give some idea to do my things...

Comment: Anyway to get it to display older submissions as well then I think you need to replace things like this `<td><?php echo $_POST['name1']; ?></td>`, which just directly prints what was posted back, with something which reads old records from the database as well. It's hard to know exactly because you didn't make clear where you store these "submissions" when they are posted.

Comment: How can I store all submission.

Comment: In the database?? That's the usual place to store things. If you only need to store it until the user leaves the application (and clear the history when they open it later) then you could use the Session to store it in memory temporarily, instead of the database.

Comment: thank you...for useful discussion.

Comment: No problem. Give it a try. If you write some code and still get stuck with a specific error or something then please ask a new question with that code and people will be happy to help you fix it.

Comment: I have updated question. Please see link     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47714778/submit-product-with-session-with-add-to-cart