# submit product with session with add to cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have asked this question before. But it is updated with ajax and add to cart.

I have a form, which have some input fields and also have some check box fields. If any one fill fields and select some checkbox and then submit. Then some data according submission shows on another div.

Now If same person again fill that fields after first submission and select checkbox and submit. Then some data according submission shows on div. But it replace old submission content. I need all submission content, on div including all old submission content.

My code is:

```
<form  class="reservation-form mb-0" action="" method="post" novalidate autocomplete="off">

    <input name="name1" class="form-control required " type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" aria-required="true" required>
    <input name="age" class="form-control required " type="number" placeholder="Enter Age" aria-required="true" required>
    <select required id="selectarea" class="form-control" name="selectgender"> 
        <option>Select Gender</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select> 

    <?php
        $query1=mysql_query("select * from lab_location_package_rel where city_id='$selectcity1' AND area_id='$selectarea1' AND lab_id='$selectlab1'") or die (mysql_error());          
        while($value = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
            $mrp=$value['mrp'];
            $opp=$value['offer_price_perc'];
            $package_id=$value['package_id'];
            $per=$mrp*$opp/100;
            $total=$mrp-$per;
            $query2=mysql_query("select * from package_master where id='$package_id'") or die (mysql_error());
            $value2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
            ?>     
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="namec[]" class="quantity<?php echo $value["id"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $value["id"]; ?>" />
                    <label for="checkbox">
                        <b>Package Name:</b> <?php $package_title1=$value2['package_title']; echo $package_title1;?> <br>
                        <b>MRP:</b>  <strike><?php $mrp1=$value['mrp']; echo $mrp1; ?>  </strike><br>
                        <b>Offer Price:</b>  <?php $total1=$total; echo $total1; ?>       
                    </label>
                </div>

            </li>
        <?php } 
    ?>
    <input type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-warning" value="Submit" onclick="add_cart('<?php echo $value["id"]; ?>')">
</form>

<div class="cart_data">
        </div>
```

My AJAX is:

```
<script>

function add_cart(p_id=""){
var quantity = $(".quantity"+p_id).val();
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"ajax_cart.php",
    data:{action:'add',p_id:p_id,quantity:quantity},
    success:function(result){
        $('.cart_data').html(result);
    }
});
}

function remove_cart(p_id){
//alert(p_id);
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"ajax_cart.php",
    data:{action:'delete',p_id:p_id},
    success:function(result){
        $('.cart_data').html(result);
    }
});
}

function empty_cart(){
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"ajax_cart.php",
    data:{action:'empty'},
    success:function(result){
        $('.cart_data').html(result);
    }
});
}

</script>
```

My ajax_cart.php is:

```
<?php
include"connection.php";
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
@$p_id   = trim($_REQUEST['p_id']);
//$_SESSION['product_cart'] = array();
if($action == 'add'){
 @$quantity = $_REQUEST['quantity'];
 if(!empty($p_id)){

                $query1=mysql_query("select * from lab_location_package_rel where id='$p_id'") or die (mysql_error());          
                 while($product_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
                 $mrp=$product_data['mrp'];
                 $opp=$product_data['offer_price_perc'];
                 $package_id=$product_data['package_id'];

                 $per=$mrp*$opp/100;
                 $total=$mrp-$per;

             $query2=mysql_query("select * from package_master where id='$package_id'") or die (mysql_error());
             $value2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
                 }


     $product = array("p_id"=>$product_data['id'],"title"=>$value2['package_title'],"price"=>$product_data['mrp']*$quantity,"image"=>$product_data['offer_price_perc']);

    if(isset($_SESSION['product_cart']) && !empty($_SESSION['product_cart']))
    {
             if(!array_key_exists($product_data['id'],$_SESSION['product_cart']))
        {

            $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_data['id']] = $product;

        }

    }
    else{
      $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_data['id']] = $product;
    }
 }    
}
if($action == "delete"){
unset($_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id]);
}

if($action == "empty"){
session_destroy();
}
?>

<div class="cart_data">          
<?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['product_cart'])){
      foreach($_SESSION['product_cart'] as $data){
      ?>
          <h5>Patient Details</h5>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Sex</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <?php //if(isset($_POST["submit"])==true)
                {
                    ?>
                <td><?php //echo $_POST['name1']; ?></td>
                <td><?php //echo $_POST['age']; ?></td>
                <td><?php //echo $_POST['selectgender']; ?></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Update</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>


        <br><br>

        <h5>Package Details</h5>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Package</th>
                <th>MRP</th>
                <th>Offer Price</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

             <tr>
                <td><?php echo $data['title'];  ?></td>
                <td><strike><?php echo $data['price']; ?></strike></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['image']; ?></td>
                <td>Delete</td>
             </tr>



                <?php
                }
                ?>



             </tr>
        </tbody></table>

      <?php }  } ?>
      </div>
```

Comment: what's your question? What's your problem? You've posted a statement of your intention, and some code. Presumably, there is a difference between what you want and what the code does. But it's a lot of code, so please identify the issue you are facing with it. What goes wrong, and where?

Comment: thank you for reply again....But I am trying it from 1 day. Please can we connect with teamviewer?

Comment: So that you can check live.

Comment: No, the question should be answerable on its own. If there's not enough info in it, and you want it answering, you need to edit it until it's meaningful. You need to find a way to describe your issue in detail. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some guidance if you're unsure. An SO question is not just for the benefit of the person asking, it's creating a public record for future readers who face similar problems. If you want 1-1 private help to solve your issue then you need to hire a consultant (and this site is not the place to recruit one)